# Rules in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to combine the following three rules in one.

```
Rule1 = Cos[m_ t]^3 Cos[n_ t] -> 0
Rule2 = Cos[1. t]^3 Cos[3. t] -> Pi/4
Rule3 = Cos[2. t]^3 Cos[6. t] -> Pi/4
```

In my present calculation, the value of m and n changes from 1 to 7 so Rule1 is not correct when (m=1,n=3) and (m=2,n=6). Is it possible to combine all these three rules in one?

Comment: Can't you just `Join` them?

Comment: If I put Rule2, Rule3 followed by Rule1, I get the desired output. However, I am looking for an even better way of writing this in Mathematica. @AndrewCheong

Comment: Can you post your calculation code as well? I believe Mathematica sorts rules by generality so there shouldn't be a difference due to ordering, unless you're invoking your computation a certain way.